# Meteor - insert nested data/object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an insert query:

```
Activity.insert ({
      activityType: this.activityType,
      bib: $("input#checkin").val(),
      "legacy.eventId": Session.get("eventIdLegacy"),
      checkpointNumber: Session.get("checkpointNumber")
    });
```

Currently, it chokes on "legacy.eventId" with the message

```
Exception while invoking method '/activity/insert' Error: key legacy.eventId must not contain '.'
```

What is the correct syntax to insert into a nested mongoldb field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `legacy` is an object array, you could insert the data as:

```
Activity.insert({
      activityType: this.activityType,
      bib: $("input#checkin").val(),
      legacy: [
            { eventId: Session.get("eventIdLegacy") }
      ],
      checkpointNumber: Session.get("checkpointNumber")
});
```

else:

```
Activity.insert({
      activityType: this.activityType,
      bib: $("input#checkin").val(),
      legacy: { 
           eventId: Session.get("eventIdLegacy") 
      },
      checkpointNumber: Session.get("checkpointNumber")
});
```